# jQuery Ajax Form redirecting to query processing page instead of staying on form

Tags: jquery

I have been trying to get this piece of code to work.  It supposed to return "Committee Alert Added" in the result span but it keeps going to the processing page.  The processing page is successful and just echos success or failure.

Here is the form

```
    <div class="addbox">
        <p>Select Committees Below</p>
        <form id="alertForm" action="process.php" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="userid" value="<?php echo $userid; ?>" />
            <input type="text" id="committeeid-input" name="committeeid" />
            <button id="sub" name="addAlert" value="addAlert">Add Alert</button>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#committeeid-input").tokenInput("http://www.orestarjunkie.com/list.php");
            });
            </script>
        </form>
        <span id="result"></span>
    </div>
```

Here is the js

```
$("#sub").click( function() {
 $.post( $("#alertForm").attr("action"), 
     $("#alertForm :input").serializeArray(), 
     function(info){ $("#result").html(info); 
     return false;
});
});

$("#alertForm").submit( function() { event.preventDefault(); });
```

I have tried return false but everything I have read says that is depreciated and use preventDefault.

Mark

Comment: It turned out to be the way I had the scripts being called.  I needed to have the js at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Do not hesitate to your solution as an answer (and mark it as the accepted answer) instead of a comment as it improves readability.

Answer (score 0):

Without testing what I think is going on, is that you have a click handler on the button.  That will eventually bubble up and result in a submit event.  You have also added another submit event handler that on submit will do nothing.  What I think you need to do instead is block your click event from bubbling up, resulting in a submit.

```
$("#sub").click( function(event) {
  $.post($("#alertForm").attr("action"), 
         $("#alertForm :input").serializeArray(), 
         function(info){ 
           $("#result").html(info); 
           return false;
         });
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Forget the second event, it does nothing.